# How to perform svn revert locally except a single file

Tags: svn, revert

I have made changes to multiple files in my folder locally for testing purposes. However, I would like to revert them back to original condition except a single file, which I still need in the present condition. Presently, I use

```
svn revert -R .
```

which reverts all of them to original condition. Could someone help me, how to use a command that excludes a single file in this operation?

Comment: you could always copy/paste the file to a diffrent location and then revert all files :)

Comment: not really a direct answer ;) But I am expecting a command line svn operation

Comment: I don't think there is a direct option for that. You can use the svn ignore on that single file but i dont know that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices:

- Add all needed to reverting files in changelist (add all, remove single file), use `revert --cl`
- Store all files in text-file (space-separated list), pass it to `revert  --target FILE`

You can also commit current state of WC into some temporary branch, revert all, merge singe file from branch to trunk

Answer (score 0):

+Update (from @lazy badger's ans):
Steps:

1. Svn status
2. Grep all the changes except the filename having the pattern
3. Remove unnecessary content (ex: M, ?, D, C)
4. Save it to a file and use --targets filename

EX: `svn status |  grep "^\M" | grep -v "pattern" | awk '{print $2}' > change.txt`
This example will first get all the modified files without the pattern and then remove the unnecessary info from the path and then save it to a file.

After this, use `svn revert --targets change.txt` to revert the files